# Pandas Out of Bounds timestamp work around

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a table from one sql server to another. There are some date values that are very far in the future (year 9000+). Pandas throws the error:

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9017-11-10 00:00:00

when trying to write or perform the pd.to_datetime() funciton on the column. I would rather not convert the column to a string before writing and was hoping there is some way to handle dates so far away?

From the googling I've done, it does seem that pandas does do this by design. I have to believe there is an alternative though as the limitation of no far distant dates (especially when the database can handle it fine) seems pretty significant.

Comment: Indeed, pandas natively uses the np datetime 64 representation for all its datetimes. I know they are working on some support of fixing this for SAS (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20927), but apparently not on SQL. Maybe a workaround: you could use plain SQLAlchemy, which pandas also uses under the hood.It transforms dates to datetime.date(), which can handle your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much @braml1. I was able to convert the dates to standard datetime values with: df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:None if pd.isnull(x) else dt.date(x.year, x.month, x.day)). This did force all time components of my datetimes to be 00:00:00.000 but luckily they were already all zero as the datetimes were really just dates.

Comment: You could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144545/how-to-handle-dates-which-is-out-of-timestamp-range-in-pandas/68144719#68144719

Answer (score 0):

The above function treats the out of bounds by setting it to its maximum supported date

```
def date_include(dataframe):
    dataframe1=dataframe.str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)[0]
    dataframe2=dataframe.str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)[1]
    dataframe1=pd.to_numeric(dataframe1.str.replace('-',''),errors='coerce')
    dataframe1.loc[dataframe1>22620411]=22620411
    dataframe1=pd.to_datetime(dataframe1,format="%Y%m%d")
    date=dataframe1.astype(str)+" "+dataframe2
    return date
```