# How to handle dates which is out of timestamp range in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I was working with the Crunchbase dataset. I have an entry of Harvard University which was founded in 1636. This entry is giving me an error when I am trying to convert string to DateTime.

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1636-09-08 00:00:00
```

I found out that pandas support timestamp from 1677

```
>>> pd.Timestamp.min
Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
```

I checked out some solutions like one suggesting using  `errors='coerce'` but dropping this entry/ making it null is not an option.
Can you please suggest a way to handle this issue?

Comment: From the docs [Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) "Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years"

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data that a datatype of timestamp is necessary? There are some good options in [Representing out-of-bounds spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  mentioned in comments by [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker), there is limitation of pandas timestamps because of its representation in float64, you could probably work around it by parsing the date-time using datetime library when needed, otherwise letting it stay as string or convert it to an integer

Scenario 1: If you plan on showing this value only when you print it

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('1636-09-08 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Scenario 2: If you want to use it as a date column to retain information in the dataframe, you could additionally

```
datetime_object.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

using it on a column in a pandas dataframe would yield this

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['1636-09-08 00:00:00'],['1635-09-09 00:00:00']], columns=['dates'])
df['str_date']=df['dates'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df.head()
```

|  | dates | str_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1636-09-08 00:00:00 | 1636-09-08 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1635-09-09 00:00:00 | 1635-09-09 00:00:00 |

pandas treats this column as a object column, but when you access it, it is a datetime column

```
df['str_date'][0]
>>datetime.datetime(1636, 9, 8, 0, 0)
```

also, adding this for the sake of completeness: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob